# Проблема с кодировкой в go

Tags: golang

Добрый день. Я при загрузке приложения загружаю из базы список людей. Потом, когда авторизуется человек, в его сессию вносятся `id`, `FIO`, ... (кирилица).

Когда я из сессии беру значение `FIO`, я получаю абракадабру. Кодировка всех файлов UTF-8 (пробовал и ANSI Windows).

Вывожу данные

```
session, _ := store.Get(r, "SessionId")
Id := session.Values["Id"].(int)
FIO := session.Values["FIO"].(string)
Role := session.Values["Role"].(string)
log.Println(
    "Клиент подключился сокет=", Soc_Id, ". id- ", Id, " ФИО- ", FIO,
    " Роль- ", Role)  // Консоль выводит "нормальные данные" 
fmt.Fprintln(w, "Привет ", FIO)  // А здесь абракадабра
```

Где менять кодировку или что делать в данной ситуации?

> Решение
>
> ```
> Если с файла
>     bs, err := ioutil.ReadFile("./templates/main.html")
>     if err != nil {
>         return
>     }
>     str := string(bs)
>     fmt.Println(str)
>     fmt.Fprintln(w, str) 
> Если просто текст, то добавить 
> w.Header().Set("Content-type", "text/html; charset=utf-8")
> fmt.Fprintln(w, "Привет <b>Роман</b>") //И русский текст отображается и теги тоже- если без хедера- то всё будет c тегами
> ```

Comment: Опишите ваше окружение, какая операционная система и так далее. Кроме того неплохо бы в таком случае еще привести конкретный вывод, что именно и где выводится.

Comment: И научитесь пользоваться языком разметки StackOverflow. Я ваше сообщение к нормальному виду привел, а вы все опять испортили.

Comment: Ок. Сорри. Я там пока не разобрался, как нормально делать. Ок-буду смотреть

Comment: @TwoRS просто не делайте отступы в 4 пробела в начале абзаца. SO воспринимает это как блок кода.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Убедитесь что файл сохранен не просто в Unicode, а именно в UTF-8, c BOM.

Первые байты файла должны быть `0xEF,0xBB,0xBF`.

Можно проверить в notepad  - открыть фай и нажать Save As - в дропдауне Encoding должно быть выбрано UTF-8, а не Unicode.

Comment: Сохранил все файлы в UTF-8 (и с Bom и без пробовал)
Поидее-если же в сессию записываются нормальные значения, а уже от туда выходят иероглифы-значит где-то там копать?
Я даже взял и gopath нашёл пакет сессий и каждый файл там сохранил в UTF-8 (и с Bom и без)- всёравно иероглифы.

Comment: @TwoRS слово Привет тоже абракадаброй выводится?

Comment: Да. Тогда,получается не в сессиях дело. Сам файл, который выводит данные- в UTF-8. Если пытаюсь компилировать в Ansi-ругается и пишет  illegal UTF-8 sequence

Comment: @TwoRS Проблема скорее всего в неправильном bom. Должен быть именно `EFBBBF`. А не `FEFF` Проверяйте первые байты. Должно быть точно [как вот в этом примере, save as](https://gist.github.com/PashaPash/972d83a5d7a47b8d5988/raw/cf59f11790ddfa62c81c93eafe675f6cd343b421/sample.go). или попробуйте удалить из файла весь текст и проверить размер - должно остаться 3 байта. Или залейте файл куда-нибудь - я попробую проверить.

Comment: Спасибо.Заработало. Я немного Вас ввёл в заблуждение и сам запутался. Т.к. раньше весь текст выводился вместе с тегами- я взял и добавил w.Header().Set("Content-type", "text/html") - в итоге получилась вся эта заморочка. Везде пославил UTF-8,а оно не работало. Если убираю пропись для хедера, то работает русский текст, но выводится простыня с html тегами. В итоге решение w.Header().Set("Content-type", "text/html; charset=utf-8"). Ещё вопрос,немного не по этой теме. А как вывести сразу файл при запросе на хендлер?

Comment: Разобрался. Спасибо большое